# About TikZ and decoration (accent in text)

Tags: tikz-pgf, languages, accents

I use the command:

```
\path [shift={(-2.75,0)},decorate, decoration={text along path, text={Plan meridien}}]
      (165:2.8) arc (165:90:2.8) ;
```

to draw a text on the circular arc path. This work well.

But I use French language, and I try to put correct accentuation on the word "méridien". The problem is then the LaTeX compilation stop, the result is not rendered. It is not possible to put any accent.

So, can I wrote French text along a path on TikZ figure? or any accent and/or special accent by this way (text decoration by TikZ)?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Are you using `babel` with the `french` option? In such cases a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem is always beneficial because people see how exactly you do it.

Answer (score 8):

According to the v2.10 manual, section 30.6, each letter of the text is typeset in its own `\hbox`.  I take this to mean that TikZ parses the `text = {...}` token-by-token, so if you wrote `Plan m\'eridien`, it would take `\'` to be its own character; since it is just an accent command, that causes an error.  Writing `Plan m{\'e}ridien` works.

**Edit:** As Altermundus says, the braces cause the accented letter `{\'e}` to be treated as a single token, which is very often the case in TeX.

Comment: This is exact. You need to use parentheses

Comment: I try the argument {\'e} and this work fine. I understand your explanation. Thanks very much !.

Comment: TikZ seems to really read the text token by token (using `\futurelet`) but if it finds a `{` it reads the group as macro argument instead. (This actually will break if `\bgroup` is used outside `{ }` because it looks like a `{` for `\ifx`.)

Comment: So there's no kerning between letters? Ouch!

Comment: @egreg: In this application (placing the letters on a path) you don't need the normal kerning anyway. Actually you need to adjust the spacing/kerning depending on the current position of the path...

Comment: I just tried to get `é` working (using `[utf8]{inputenc}`) but it also requires braces. Does `\let\mymacro=é` only take the first byte of the multi-byte character? I mean with the normal `pdflatex`. This would explain the errors I get without the braces.

Comment: @Martin: Your diagnosis is correct. What you *see* (the "é") is a character, but actually TeX sees the two bytes `^^c3` and `^^a9`. So `\let\mymacro=é` is `\let\mymacro=^^c3` and `^^a9` remains in the input stream, probably printing as ©.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for confirming this. I actually got an `Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined in inputencoding 'utf8'` error. The `^^a9` alone seems not be valid with `[utf8]{inputenc}`.

Comment: Is there a mean to avoid having to add curly braces ? I'm building a macro to draw such a thing, and I don't have control on the macro parameters (multi-lingual document)...