# Circular Arrows and Text on Path

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I did some basic tikz figures, but i have absolutely no idea how to do a figure like this:

[image]

Each text block should be aligned on a circular path and centered within the arrows.
Could anyone please provide me an example how to get such a figure or give me a brief idea of where to start?

Comment: This is where you could start: [`smartdiagram` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/smartdiagram).

Comment: You may find some tips in [Polar Histograms](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87649/polar-histograms).

Comment: Both packages are amazing. I will have a closer look. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create it quite easily with arcs:

### Code

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\newcommand{\arcarrow}[8]% inner radius, middle radius, outer radius, start angle, end angle, tip protusion angle, options, text
{   \pgfmathsetmacro{\rin}{#1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rmid}{#2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rout}{#3}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\astart}{#4}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\aend}{#5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\atip}{#6}
    \fill[#7] (\astart:\rin) arc (\astart:\aend:\rin) -- (\aend+\atip:\rmid) -- (\aend:\rout) arc (\aend:\astart:\rout) -- (\astart+\atip:\rmid) -- cycle;
    \path[decoration={text along path, text={#8}, text align={align=center}, raise=-0.5ex},decorate] (\astart+\atip:\rmid) arc (\astart+\atip:\aend+\atip:\rmid);
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[even odd rule,red!30] circle (3.8) circle (3.2);
    \foreach \x in {0,60,...,300} 
    {   \arcarrow{3}{3.5}{4}{\x+20}{\x+70}{5}{red,draw=red!50!black,very thick}{text \x}
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly i was looking for! thank you.

Comment: @TomBombadil: The text decorations doesn't support accented characters or different encodings?

Comment: I've found the solution: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21589/about-tikz-and-decoration-accent-in-text

Comment: I like this solution! I added it to the [TeXample TikZ gallery](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/circular-arrows-text/).

Comment: +1 An interesting solution, but becomes counter-intuitive when you want to change from anti-clockwise to clockwise: tip protrusion angle has to be changed to negative, as the order of angles makes no difference.  I am in a bit hurry now, so I don't have time to edit and propose my own solution, but maybe some other time.

Comment: Is it also possible to position the \arcarrow relative to a node? Such that there is a node at (-2,0) and the circle’s center is at (-2,0)?

Answer (score 0):

The answer below uses the [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote.

The initial settings are `value=\WCvarA`, `slices style=\WCvarB` and `data=\WCvarC`. For this figure, the key `value=1` is used so that each arrow has the same size. The key `data` is empty.

The number is obtained with `\WCcount`. The arrows are obtained with `slices arrow={1}{0}`. The gap between the arrows is obtained with `gap polar=5`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\sffamily
\fill[Maroon!40,even odd rule] (0,0) circle[radius=2.8] circle[radius=2.2];
\wheelchart[
  arc data=Step \WCcount\\\WCvarB,
  arc data angle shift=7,
  arc data expand=f,
  arc data pos=0.5,
  arc data style={text color=white},
  data=,
  gap polar=5,
  slices arrow={1}{0},
  slices style=Maroon!\WCvarA,
  value=1
]{%
  100/text abc,
  90/text def,
  80/text ghi,
  70/text jkl%
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```