# Label in cyclic arrow diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, arrows, labels

Consider the following code from [TeXample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/overlapping-arrows/):

[image]

How to refactor it for adding sloped labels on the outside of the arrows? Do you have a more elegant solution with TikZ?

```
% Overlapping arrows
% Author: Elena Botoeva
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.3cm, paperwidth=3.3cm, paperheight=3.3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,0.6}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.6,0.1,0.1}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0.2,0.6,0.2}

\def\arrow{
  (10.75:1.1) -- (6.5:1) arc (6.25:120:1) [rounded corners=0.5] --
  (120:0.9) [rounded corners=1] -- (130:1.1) [rounded corners=0.5] --
  (120:1.3) [sharp corners] -- (120:1.2) arc (120:5.25:1.2)
  [rounded corners=1] -- (10.75:1.1) -- (6.5:1) -- cycle
}

\tikzset{
  ashadow/.style={opacity=.25, shadow xshift=0.07, shadow yshift=-0.07},
}

\def\arrows[#1]{         
  \begin{scope}[scale=#1]
    \draw[color=darkred, %
    drop shadow={ashadow, color=red!60!black}] \arrow;

    \draw[color=darkgreen, bottom color=green!90!black, top color=green!60, %
    drop shadow={ashadow, color=green!60!black}] [rotate=120] \arrow;

    \draw[color=darkblue, right color=blue, left color=blue!60, %
    drop shadow={ashadow, color=blue!60!black}] [rotate=240] \arrow;

    % to hide the green shadow
    \draw[color=darkred, left color=red, right color=red!60] \arrow;
  \end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \arrows[1];
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I answered a [similar question here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114562/circular-arrows-and-text-on-path/114590#114590), you can adapt it for instance by altering the `raise` key, probably also by myking it an argument of the macro.

Comment: @TomBombadil: Simply beautiful, I'll try your solution later. Thanks.

Comment: @TomBombadil: Could you please check my comment there?

Comment: It appears it does not work for special characters, but I have no idea why. Probably you should ask a new question about it?

Comment: @TomBombadil: Ok, I'll open a new question. Thank you again.