# Reproducing a figure in tikz with text and arrows flowing round in a circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

I want to reproduce the following figure with `tikz` (because there is a typo in the text in this figure).
[image]

My `tikz` code is (borrowed from [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/pdca-cycle/))

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{208,208,208}
\definecolor{mymagenta}{RGB}{226,0,116}
\newcommand*{\mytextstyle}{\sffamily\Large\bfseries\color{black!85}}
\newcommand{\arcarrow}[3]{%
   % inner radius, middle radius, outer radius, start angle,
   % end angle, tip protusion angle, options, text
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\rin}{1.7}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\rmid}{2.2}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\rout}{2.7}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\astart}{#1}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\aend}{#2}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\atip}{5}
   \fill[mygray, very thick] (\astart+\atip:\rin)
                         arc (\astart+\atip:\aend:\rin)
      -- (\aend-\atip:\rmid)
      -- (\aend:\rout)   arc (\aend:\astart+\atip:\rout)
      -- (\astart:\rmid) -- cycle;
   \path[
      decoration = {
         text along path,
         text = {|\mytextstyle|#3},
         text align = {align = center},
         raise = -1.0ex
      },
      decorate
   ](\astart+\atip:\rmid) arc (\astart+\atip:\aend+\atip:\rmid);
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \fill[even odd rule, mymagenta] circle (1.5);

   \node at (0,0) [
      font  = \mytextstyle,
      color = white,
      align = center
   ]{
      Learn\\
      $6\sigma$
   };

   \arcarrow{ 85}{3}{Define}
   \arcarrow{290}{357}{Measure}
   \arcarrow{210}{289}{Analyze}
   \arcarrow{206}{146}{Improve}
   \arcarrow{130}{96}{Control}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

and the output is

[image]

I need hints to get my figure more close the original one. Thanks

Comment: If you do not need the exact duplicate, have a look at the smartdiagram package: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/smartdiagram/smartdiagram.pdf

Comment: Thank @UweZiegenhagen for pointing out a good package. I'm not looking for an exact duplicate but close to the original one.

Comment: A typo? which typo do you refer to just out of curiosity?   On a side note I do notice a typo in your TEX version, namely Learn should be LEAN (Lean six sigma is the name of the methodology).

Comment: On [TeXample](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/overlapping-arrows/)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118717/138900

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is certainly possible to draw something of this sort. (I did not attempt to match the colors. **UPDATE**: corrected the orientation of the lower-most text, big thanks to manooooh!)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,arrows.meta,bending}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand{\LineWidth}{10mm}
\newcommand{\Radius}{3cm}
\node[font=\sffamily\bfseries,scale=3.4,anchor=south] at (0,-0.1) {LEARN};
\node[font=\sffamily,scale=6,anchor=north] at (0,0.5) {6\textsigma};
\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {yellow!50!orange,gray!50,cyan!50,gray,red}
{\draw[line width=\LineWidth,\X] ({90-(\Y-1)*72}:\Radius)
 arc({90-(\Y-1)*72}:{90-(\Y)*72}:\Radius);}

\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {yellow!50!orange,gray!50,cyan!50,gray,red}
{\draw[-{Triangle[bend,length={0.75*\LineWidth},width={1.5*\LineWidth}]},
line width=\LineWidth,\X] 
({90-(\Y-0.5)*72}:\Radius)
 arc({90-(\Y-0.5)*72}:{90-(\Y)*72-10}:\Radius);}

\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {Define,Measure,Analyze,Improve,Control} 
{\ifnum\Y=3
\fill[decoration={text along path, text={|\Large\bfseries| \X},
  raise=-3pt,text color=white,text align=center},decorate] 
  ({90-(\Y)*72}:\Radius)
 arc({90-(\Y)*72}:{90-(\Y-1)*72}:\Radius);
\else
\fill[decoration={text along path, text={|\Large\bfseries| \X},
  raise=-3pt,text color=white,text align=center},decorate] 
  ({90-(\Y-1)*72}:\Radius)
 arc({90-(\Y-1)*72}:{90-(\Y)*72}:\Radius);
\fi }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM FOR FUN**: I was trying to make the corners of the arrow path round. One can design arbitrary arrows with `\pgfdeclarearrow`, and the basis of my attempt is the example on p. 1096 of the pgfmanual. I could, however, not make `\pgfsetcornersarced` work. (If I would have to guess, I'd probably say that this is because the examples on pp. 1069 of the pgfmanual use `\pgfusepath{stroke}`, the analogon of which is `\pgfusepath{fill}`. However, this is not allowed in a arrow declaration, where one has to use the quick version `\pgfusepathqfill`, which, according to what I found, ignores `\pgfsetcornersarced`.) But [@circumscribe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/156366/circumscribe) has a [much better solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/469912/121799), which I shamelessly copy here. The only minor improvement (?) is that I move the texts a bit away from the arrow heads, but full credits go to [@circumscribe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/156366/circumscribe).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,arrows.meta,bending}
\pgfdeclarearrow{
 name =rtriangle,
 parameters = { \the\pgfarrowlength },
  setup code = {
    % The different end values:
    \pgfarrowssettipend{.25\pgfarrowlength}
   \pgfarrowssetlineend{-.25\pgfarrowlength}
   \pgfarrowssetvisualbackend{-.5\pgfarrowlength}
   \pgfarrowssetbackend{-.75\pgfarrowlength}
% The hull
\pgfarrowshullpoint{.5\pgfarrowlength}{0pt}
\pgfarrowshullpoint{-.5\pgfarrowlength}{\pgfarrowlength}
\pgfarrowshullpoint{-.5\pgfarrowlength}{-\pgfarrowlength} % Saves: Only the length:
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfarrowlength
  },
  drawing code = {
   \pgfsetroundjoin
   \pgfsetlinewidth{.2\pgflinewidth}
   \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{.5\pgfarrowlength}{0\pgfarrowlength}}
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-.5\pgfarrowlength}{\pgfarrowlength}}
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.5\pgfarrowlength}{-\pgfarrowlength}}
   \pgfpathclose
   \pgfusepathqfillstroke
},
 defaults = { length = 4cm }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand{\LineWidth}{10mm}
\newcommand{\Radius}{3cm}
\node[font=\sffamily\bfseries,scale=3.4,anchor=south] at (0,-0.1) {LEARN};
\node[font=\sffamily,scale=6,anchor=north] at (0,0.5) {6\textsigma};
\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {yellow!50!orange,gray!50,cyan!50,gray,red}
{\draw[line width=\LineWidth,\X] ({90-(\Y-1)*72}:\Radius)
arc({90-(\Y-1)*72}:{90-(\Y)*72}:\Radius);}
%`,width={1.5*\LineWidth}
\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {yellow!50!orange,gray!50,cyan!50,gray,red}
{\draw[-{rtriangle[bend,length={0.65*\LineWidth}]},
line width=\LineWidth,\X]
({90-(\Y-0.5)*72}:\Radius)
arc({90-(\Y-0.5)*72}:{90-(\Y)*72-10}:\Radius);}

\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {Define,Measure,Analyze,Improve,Control}
{\ifnum\Y=3
\fill[decoration={text along path, text={|\Large\bfseries| \X},
 raise=-3pt,text color=white,text align=center},decorate]
 ({90-(\Y)*72-5}:\Radius)
arc({90-(\Y)*72-5}:{90-(\Y-1)*72-5}:\Radius);
\else
\fill[decoration={text along path, text={|\Large\bfseries| \X},
 raise=-3pt,text color=white,text align=center},decorate]
 ({90-(\Y-1)*72-5}:\Radius)
arc({90-(\Y-1)*72-5}:{90-(\Y)*72-5}:\Radius);
\fi }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

P.S. As for the question whether "LEAN" or "LEARN" is correct, I really don't now. However, "lean" does not sound right to marmots (a lean marmot won't survive the winter). So I kept "learn". ;-)

Comment: It looks nice! The lower letters should be rotated by `180°`, isn't it?

Comment: @manooooh Gracias!

Comment: @marmot: [Re:addendum for fun] You can use set positive line width and use `\pgfsetroundjoin`, like this: https://pastebin.com/EMuecMat

Comment: @Circumscribe Oh WOW! Do you want to post this? It is certainly much more elegant than what I did.

Comment: It's not really a new answer to the question though…

Comment: @Circumscribe It is a nice way of generating something very close to the screenshot of the OP, so why is this not an answer?

Comment: @marmot: Because it's just a modification of your answer. I can post it though (once I've read what the rest of your code does :) ).

Comment: @Circumscribe It is completely up to you and I believe I understand what you are saying. So I will certainly not push you. (If you post your answer I can still use it to improve yours, but this way I would have a way to give proper credit to your idea, which I definitely did not have. Another way would be that I ask a question how to do this, and you answer this, this would lead to a model one answer per question, and the arrow with rounded corners will be more visible. Either way is fine. But I do think your observation is really cool.)

Comment: @marmot: ↓↓ I've posted an answer, see below. ↓↓

Comment: @marmot, for those who would want the ligatures maintained on the curved baseline (e.g. me), as in the word “define”, do it think this could be achieved?

Comment: @oliversm: You can replace "Define" by "De{fi}ne".

Answer (score 23):

Here's an augmented version of [marmot's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/469868/156366), per his request.

The main improvement is the arrowheads, which now have rounded corners. 
I'm using a custom arrowhead for this because the `\Triangle[round,line width=0pt .1]` arrowhead is unfortunately disconnected from its shaft if the head is relatively small in comparison to the line width (as it is in this case). (And also because marmot asked for it.)

Arrowheads with rounded corners can be declared with `\pgfdeclarearrow` by setting a positive line width with `\pgfsetlinewidth{<radius>}`, calling `\pgfsetroundjoin` and stroking the path tracing out the arrowhead in addition to filling it with `\pgfusepathqfillstroke`. This can be seen in the preamble below.
More information about declaring arrow tips can be found in the [pgf manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) (§104.4 on p1093 as of this writing, §100.4 on p1017 before 05 jan 2019), but I would also *highly* recommend taking a look at the source of the [`arrows.meta`](http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/graphics/pgf/base/tex/pgflibraryarrows.meta.code.tex) library to see some examples.

Here's the result:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2.718281828mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{textgreek}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,arrows.meta,bending}

\pgfdeclarearrow{
  name = mytriangle,
  parameters = { \the\pgfarrowlength, \the\pgfarrowwidth, \the\pgfarrowlinewidth, \ifpgfarrowroundcap c\fi },
  defaults = { length = 0pt .85, width = 0pt 1.3, line width = 0pt .1, round = true },
  setup code = {
    %% The different end values:
    \pgfarrowssettipend{1\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowssetlineend{.2\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowssetvisualbackend{0\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowssetbackend{0\pgfarrowwidth}
    %% The hull:
    \pgfarrowshullpoint{1\pgfarrowlength}{0\pgfarrowwidth}
    \pgfarrowsupperhullpoint{0\pgfarrowlength}{.5\pgfarrowwidth}
    %% Values that are used when drawing:
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfarrowwidth
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfarrowlength
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfarrowlinewidth
  },
  drawing code = {
    \ifpgfarrowroundcap\pgfsetroundjoin\fi
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfarrowlinewidth}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{1\pgfarrowlength}{0\pgfarrowwidth}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0\pgfarrowlength}{.5\pgfarrowwidth}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0\pgfarrowlength}{-.5\pgfarrowwidth}}
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgfusepathqfillstroke
  },
}

\definecolor{myred}{rgb}{.92,.26,.23}
\definecolor{myyellow}{rgb}{.97,.69,.21}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{.54,.53,.55}
\definecolor{mycyan}{rgb}{.38,.66,.65}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{.07,.24,.32}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand*{\LineWidth}{1.2cm}
    \newcommand*{\Radius}{3cm}
    %% Text:
    \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries,scale=3.4,anchor=south,color=myblue] at (0,-0.1) {LEAN};
    \node[font=\sffamily,scale=6,anchor=north,color=myblue] at (0,0.5) {6\textsigma};
    %% Arrows:
    \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {myyellow,myred,myblue,mycyan,mygray} {
        \draw[-mytriangle,line width=\LineWidth,\X,rotate=72*(\Y-1)]
             (100:\Radius) arc (100:5:\Radius);
    }
    %% One arrowhead needs to be redrawn because it is covered
    \draw[-mytriangle,line width=\LineWidth,myyellow]
         (45:\Radius) arc (45:5:\Radius);
    %% Text on arrows:
    \foreach \X/\reverse [count=\Y] in {De{fi}ne/true,Control/true,Improve/false,Analyze/false,Measure/false} {
        \path[rotate=72*(\Y-1),decorate,decoration={text along path,text={|\Large\bfseries|\X},
                raise=-2.5pt,text color=white,text align=center,reverse path=\reverse}]
             (52-36:\Radius) arc(52-36:52+36:\Radius);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output with custom arrow]

Note that I've used the `reverse path` key to flip "Define" and "Control" and am using the `rotate` key to rotate the arrows by multiples of 72 º instead performing these computations inside the `\draw` command. One arrowhead is drawn twice because they form  circle and one of them will thus always be at the bottom.

---

---

Here is a version that uses the round version of the `Triangle` arrowhead.
Because this arrowhead is partially disconnected from its shaft if it only extends a little at the sides I'm drawing the arrowheads separately from the shafts, which also fixes the overlap problem.

The result is mostly identical:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2.718281828mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{textgreek}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,arrows.meta,bending}

\tikzset{mytriangle/.tip={Triangle[length = 0pt .95,width=0pt 1.45,round,line width=0pt .1]}}

\definecolor{myred}{rgb}{.92,.26,.23}
\definecolor{myyellow}{rgb}{.97,.69,.21}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{.54,.53,.55}
\definecolor{mycyan}{rgb}{.38,.66,.65}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{.07,.24,.32}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand*{\LineWidth}{1.2cm}
    \newcommand*{\Radius}{3cm}
    %% Text:
    \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries,scale=3.4,anchor=south,color=myblue] at (0,-0.1) {LEAN};
    \node[font=\sffamily,scale=6,anchor=north,color=myblue] at (0,0.5) {6\textsigma};
    %% Arrow shafts:
    \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {myyellow,myred,myblue,mycyan,mygray} {
        \draw[line width=\LineWidth,\X,rotate=72*(\Y-1)]
             (95:\Radius) arc (95:20:\Radius);
    }
    %% Arrowheads
    \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {myyellow,myred,myblue,mycyan,mygray} {
        \draw[-mytriangle,line width=\LineWidth,\X,rotate=72*(\Y-1)]
             (35:\Radius) arc (35:5:\Radius);
    }
    %% Text on arrows:
    \foreach \X/\reverse [count=\Y] in {De{fi}ne/true,Control/true,Improve/false,Analyze/false,Measure/false} {
        \path[rotate=72*(\Y-1),decorate,decoration={text along path,text={|\Large\bfseries|\X},
                raise=-2.5pt,text color=white,text align=center,reverse path=\reverse}]
             (52-36:\Radius) arc(52-36:52+36:\Radius);

    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output with rounded Triangle]

Comment: +20 OK I can only give +1 ... for `border=2.718281828mm`, let's say ;-)

Comment: @marmot: I suppose marmots prefer π, since it's rather more delicious :).

Comment: Actually π would've been more appropriate for a circumscribe like me, but you had already claimed it. Circumscribes love drawing circles around things though, so I'm content.

Comment: Positioning of "Control" and "Define" was suboptimal because of a space between `|\Large\bfseries|` and `\X`. Fixed now.

Comment: "I've indented my code" + ":)"... ok bad boy, if you think that with that you can harm @marmot you are wrong, but as you declare yourself a compulsive person I understand all your improvements. Oh, btw here you have: +1.

Comment: @manooooh: Perhaps that does sound a little aggressive, and it certainly served little purpose. Apologies.

Comment: @manooooh I didn't interpret it in any negative way. It is true that one could indent the code more. In the end it boils down to what editor you are using, i.e. whether it has sufficient syntax highlighting and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote, can be used.

The initial settings are `value=\WCvarA`, `slices style=\WCvarB` and `data=\WCvarC`. For this figure, we set `value=1` so that each arrow is the same size. We also set the key `data` empty.

The text in the arcs is given to the key `arc data`. The direction of this text depends on the angle of the middle of the arc given by `\WCmidangle` which is used in the key `arc data dir`. This text is centered in the arc with `arc data pos=0.5`.

The arrows are obtained with the key `slices arrow={1}{-0.3}`. The first argument is `1` so that the arrow is rectangular. The second argument is `-0.3`, the inner radius is `1.5` and the outer radius is `2.5`. Hence the distance that the arrow protrudes is 0.15. Thus the option `gap=0.075` is used to not let the arrows overlap.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\definecolor{myyellow}{rgb}{.97,.69,.21}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{.54,.53,.55}
\definecolor{mycyan}{rgb}{.38,.66,.65}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{.07,.24,.32}
\definecolor{myred}{rgb}{.92,.26,.23}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\wheelchart[
  arc data=|\bfseries|\WCvarB,
  arc data angle shift=7,
  arc data dir={\WCmidangle<180?1:-1},
  arc data pos=0.5,
  arc data style={text color=white},
  data=,
  gap=0.075,
  middle=LEAN\\$6\sigma$,
  middle style={font=\Huge\sffamily,myblue},
  radius={1.5}{2.5},
  slices arrow={1}{-0.3},
  slices style=\WCvarA,
  value=1
]{%
  myyellow/Define,
  mygray/Measure,
  mycyan/Analyze,
  myblue/Improve,
  myred/Control%
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```