# Question regarding plot

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need some orientation with this picture. I was told it was fully made in LateX. Could you give me a hint? I really appreciate it!

[image]

Comment: Well, if this is made with LaTeX, most likely this means TikZ, pstricks, asymptote or metapost. I believe to have seen these arrows produced with TikZ, perhaps on TeXample.net.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A nice person pic has been defined in [this nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/186478/121799) and the bent arrows are borrowed from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/469868/121799). I merely patched them together to obtain

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/cfr/soul base dimension}{5pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}[person/.pic={% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/186478/121799
    \node[#1] (-head) [circle, minimum size=4*\pgfkeysvalueof{/cfr/soul base dimension}] {};
    \node[#1] (-torso) [below=0pt of -head, rectangle, rounded corners=.4*\pgfkeysvalueof{/cfr/soul base dimension}, minimum width=3.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/cfr/soul base dimension}, minimum height=6*\pgfkeysvalueof{/cfr/soul base dimension}] {};
    \node[#1] (-right arm) [right=0pt of -torso.north east, yshift=-3.1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/cfr/soul base dimension}, rectangle, minimum width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/cfr/soul base dimension}, minimum height=6*\pgfkeysvalueof{/cfr/soul base dimension}, rounded corners=.4*\pgfkeysvalueof{/cfr/soul base dimension}] {};
    \node[#1] (-left arm) [left=0pt of -torso.north west, yshift=-3.1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/cfr/soul base dimension}, rectangle, minimum width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/cfr/soul base dimension}, minimum height=6*\pgfkeysvalueof{/cfr/soul base dimension}, rounded corners=.4*\pgfkeysvalueof{/cfr/soul base dimension}] {};
    \node[#1] (-left leg) [below=0pt of -torso.south, rectangle, minimum width=1.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/cfr/soul base dimension}, minimum height=6*\pgfkeysvalueof{/cfr/soul base dimension}, rounded corners=.2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/cfr/soul base dimension}, anchor=north east] {};
    \node[#1] (-right leg) [below=0pt of -torso.south, rectangle, minimum width=1.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/cfr/soul base dimension}, minimum height=6*\pgfkeysvalueof{/cfr/soul base dimension}, rounded corners=.2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/cfr/soul base dimension}, anchor=north west] {};
    \draw[#1] [rounded corners=.2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/cfr/soul base dimension}] (-right leg.south) -- (-right leg.south west) -- (-left leg.south east) -- (-left leg.south west)  -- (-torso.south west) [rounded corners=.4*\pgfkeysvalueof{/cfr/soul base dimension}] -- (-left arm.south east) -- (-left arm.south west) -- (-left arm.north west) -- (-torso.north west) -- ($(-head.south) - (.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/cfr/soul base dimension},0)$) arc [start angle=255.5, end angle=-74.5, radius=2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/cfr/soul base dimension}] -- (-torso.north east) -- (-right arm.north east) -- (-right arm.south east)  -- (-right arm.south west) [rounded corners=.2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/cfr/soul base dimension}] -- (-torso.south east)  -- (-right leg.south east) -- (-right leg.south west);
  },font=\sffamily,
  arc arrows/.cd,width/.initial=6mm,radius/.initial=1.2cm]
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=M]
   \begin{scope}[local bounding box=arc arrow]
    \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {gray!30,black,gray!50}
     {\draw[line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arc arrows/width},\X]
     ({180-(\Y+1)*120}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arc arrows/radius})
      arc({180-(\Y+1)*120}:{180-(\Y)*120}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arc arrows/radius});}
    \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {gray!30,black,gray!50}
     {\draw[-{Triangle[bend,length={0.75*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arc arrows/width}},width={1.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arc arrows/width}}]},
     line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arc arrows/width},\X] 
     ({180-(\Y+0.2)*120}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arc arrows/radius})
      arc({180-(\Y+0.2)*120}:{180-(\Y-0.5)*120-10}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arc arrows/radius});}
    \path (-1.6,0)    (1.6,0);    
   \end{scope}   
   \node[above=1em of arc arrow,align=center,node font=\large]{Recommender\\ System};
   \node[below=1em of arc arrow,align=center]{Model};
  \end{scope}    
  \draw let \p1=($(M.north)-(M.south)$) in 
  ([xshift=-\y1/2]M.south) coordinate (BL) rectangle ([xshift=\y1/2]M.north)
  coordinate (TR);
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=L,xshift=-6cm]
  \path foreach  \Coord in {(0.5,1.8),(-0.5,1.9),(-0.1,1.5),(-0.7,1.2),(0.7,1.1)} 
    { \Coord pic{person={fill=white}}};
  \end{scope}    
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=R,xshift=7cm]
  \path foreach  \Coord in {(0.5,1.8),(-0.5,1.9),(-0.1,1.5),(-0.7,1.2),(0.7,1.1)} 
  { \Coord pic{person={fill=white}}};
  \end{scope}    
  \draw[line width=4mm,-stealth,shorten <=0.5em,shorten >=0.5em] 
  (L.east|-M) -- (BL|-M)node[midway,above=1em]{Ratings};
  \draw[line width=1mm,-stealth,shorten <=0.5em,shorten >=0.5em] 
  (TR|-M) -- (R.west|-M)node[midway,above]{Recommendations};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is there a way to make the rectangle look like a square? I am playing with the parameters but I cannot find it.

Comment: @naveganteX I made it a square (and decouple now).