# Unable to change the text of PGF decoration

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-arrows

A follow up to  the answer of @TomBombadil on [Circular Arrows and Text on Path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114590/412). I am trying to tweak the text's size and/or color and the compilation gets stuck on:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
```

In particular, I tried to replace the `text={#8}` in the last line of the definition of the macro `\arcarrow` to something like `\text={\large #8}` but it didn't work. Any ideas?

For completeness, here is the code I try to compile:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\newcommand{\arcarrow}[8]% inner radius, middle radius, outer radius, start angle, end angle, tip protusion angle, options, text
{   \pgfmathsetmacro{\rin}{#1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\rmid}{#2}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\rout}{#3}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\astart}{#4}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\aend}{#5}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\atip}{#6}
  \fill[#7] (\astart:\rin) arc (\astart:\aend:\rin) -- (\aend+\atip:\rmid) -- (\aend:\rout) arc (\aend:\astart:\rout) -- (\astart+\atip:\rmid) -- cycle;
  \path[decoration={text along path, text={\large #8}, text align={align=center}, raise=-0.5ex},decorate] (\astart+\atip:\rmid) arc (\astart+\atip:\aend+\atip:\rmid);
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \arcarrow{3}{4}{5}{10}{110}{10}{red,draw=red!20!black,very thick}{Parameterization}
  \arcarrow{3}{4}{5}{130}{230}{10}{red,draw=red!20!black,very thick}{Approximation}
  \arcarrow{3}{4}{5}{250}{350}{10}{red,draw=red!20!black,very thick}{Implementation}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution like this: Use `|\large|`, `|\Huge|` , etc.,  for font declaration:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\tikzstyle{line node} = [font=\large ]
\newcommand{\arcarrow}[8]% inner radius, middle radius, outer radius, start angle, end angle, tip protusion angle, options, text
{   \pgfmathsetmacro{\rin}{#1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\rmid}{#2}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\rout}{#3}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\astart}{#4}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\aend}{#5}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\atip}{#6}
  \fill[#7] (\astart:\rin) arc (\astart:\aend:\rin) -- (\aend+\atip:\rmid) -- (\aend:\rout) arc (\aend:\astart:\rout) -- (\astart+\atip:\rmid) -- cycle;
  \path[decoration={text along path, text={|\Huge| #8}, text align={align=center}, raise=-0.5ex},decorate] (\astart+\atip:\rmid) arc (\astart+\atip:\aend+\atip:\rmid);
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \arcarrow{3}{4}{5}{10}{110}{10}{red,draw=red!20!black,very thick}{Parameterization}
  \arcarrow{3}{4}{5}{130}{230}{10}{red,draw=red!20!black,very thick}{Approximation}
  \arcarrow{3}{4}{5}{250}{350}{10}{red,draw=red!20!black,very thick}{Implementation}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Seems like this is documented in the PGF's manual under `/pgf/decoration/text=⟨text⟩`.