# Improving TikZ curved arrow with decorated path text

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations, circles

I have two questions working with this example: [Circular Arrows and Text on Path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114562/circular-arrows-and-text-on-path) 1. Is it possible to position the \arcarrow relative to some node? 2. Is it possible to have the text in the arrows 0, 60, 120 running from left to right instead of upside down? That would be (less logical but) easier to read.

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\newcommand{\arcarrow}[8]% inner radius, middle radius, outer radius, start angle, end angle, tip protusion angle, options, text
{   \pgfmathsetmacro{\rin}{#1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rmid}{#2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rout}{#3}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\astart}{#4}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\aend}{#5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\atip}{#6}
    \fill[#7] (\astart:\rin) arc (\astart:\aend:\rin) -- (\aend+\atip:\rmid) -- (\aend:\rout) arc (\aend:\astart:\rout) -- (\astart+\atip:\rmid) -- cycle;
    \path[decoration={text along path, text={#8}, text align={align=center}, raise=-0.5ex},decorate] (\astart+\atip:\rmid) arc (\astart+\atip:\aend+\atip:\rmid);
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[even odd rule,red!30] circle (3.8) circle (3.2);
    \foreach \x in {0,60,...,300} 
    {   \arcarrow{3}{3.5}{4}{\x+20}{\x+70}{5}{red,draw=red!50!black,very thick}{text \x}
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sketch of you that should look?