# \% symbol leads to superlong (forever?) compilations

Tags: tikz-pgf

This problem occurs when I am trying to improve my answer in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/481925/156344).

---

You can compile this code very well

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{bending,decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\sffamily
\node (a) at (-2,0) {probability};
\node[align=center] (b) at (2,0) {percent\\change};
\draw[-latex,postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=1ex,text along path,text align=center,text={multiply by 100}}}] (a) to[out=60,in=120] (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

but **don't compile this code**!

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{bending,decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\sffamily
\node (a) at (-2,0) {probability};
\node[align=center] (b) at (2,0) {percent\\change};
\draw[-latex,postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=1ex,text along path,text align=center,text={multiply by 100\%}}}] (a) to[out=60,in=120] (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have been waiting for more than 200 seconds

[image]

Why? I just want to add a percent symbol (`\%`)!

I think Ti*k*Z understood my `\%` as `%`, but removing the `\` throws many errors.

I even used `siunitx`, but got the same result.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{bending,decorations.text}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\sffamily
\node (a) at (-2,0) {probability};
\node[align=center] (b) at (2,0) {percent\\change};
\draw[-latex,postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=1ex,text along path,text align=center,text={multiply by \SI{100}{\percent}}}}] (a) to[out=60,in=120] (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

So, what's going on?

Comment: Very nice your 2nd image: How do I find the compilation time? Do you have any specific software where you can see the build time? My regards.

Comment: @Sebastiano I use VS Code. The LaTeX Workshop extension gives me a link to see the compilation process, which I don't use really often, but it is very useful in strange situations, like this situation.

Comment: Is this :-)? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=James-Yu.latex-workshop

Comment: @Sebastiano Yes, that's it.

Comment: The infinite loop is triggered by any unexpandable control sequence token, even by `\relax` (except implicit character tokens that raise errors). Bracing the token is the right way to go.

Comment: A similar problem is described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21589/4427

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You only need to wrap `\%` into `{...}`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{bending,decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\sffamily
\node (a) at (-2,0) {probability};
\node[align=center] (b) at (2,0) {percent\\change};
\draw[-latex,postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=1ex,text along path,text
align=center,text={multiply by 100{\%}}}}] (a) to[out=60,in=120] (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's easier (why didn't I try this?). Thumbs up!

Comment: @Skillmon I tried this only after recalling [this discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417836/121799), which almost drove me crazy,

Comment: @Skillmon marmot really drove me crazy with this solution. I'm feeling stupid now :))

Comment: @JouleV So sorry. ;-)

Comment: @JouleV Most likely stackexchange is run by the sociology department of Harvard, who want to explore the mind sets of humans (and ducks, koalas and marmots ;-).

Answer (score 12):

You can make this work by changing the `%` character to not be the comment character anymore using `\catcode`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{bending,decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\sffamily
\node (a) at (-2,0) {probability};
\node[align=center] (b) at (2,0) {percent\\change};
\begin{scope}
\catcode`\%=12
\draw[-latex,postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=1ex,text along path,text
align=center,text={multiply by 100%}}}] (a) to[out=60,in=120] (b);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem. However, could you please add some explanation about why `\%` doesn't work?

Comment: @JouleV for that I'd have to dig through the internals of Ti*k*Z, which isn't something I feel like right now, sorry.