# Modifying arcarrow

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have found this PDCA cycle (plan, do, check, act) here

http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/pdca-cycle/

```
% PDCA cycle
% Author: tikzanfaenger, Helmut, and Bartman
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{208,208,208}
\definecolor{mymagenta}{RGB}{226,0,116}
\newcommand*{\mytextstyle}{\sffamily\Large\bfseries\color{black!85}}
\newcommand{\arcarrow}[3]{%
   % inner radius, middle radius, outer radius, start angle,
   % end angle, tip protusion angle, options, text
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\rin}{1.7}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\rmid}{2.2}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\rout}{2.7}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\astart}{#1}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\aend}{#2}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\atip}{5}
   \fill[mygray, very thick] (\astart+\atip:\rin)
                         arc (\astart+\atip:\aend:\rin)
      -- (\aend-\atip:\rmid)
      -- (\aend:\rout)   arc (\aend:\astart+\atip:\rout)
      -- (\astart:\rmid) -- cycle;
   \path[
      decoration = {
         text along path,
         text = {|\mytextstyle|#3},
         text align = {align = center},
         raise = -1.0ex
      },
      decorate
   ](\astart+\atip:\rmid) arc (\astart+\atip:\aend+\atip:\rmid);
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \fill[even odd rule,mymagenta] circle (1.5);

   \node at (0,0) [
      font  = \mytextstyle,
      color = white,
      align = center
   ]{
      PDCA\\
      Cycle
   };
   \arcarrow{ 85}{  3}{ PLAN  }
   \arcarrow{270}{357}{ DO    }
   \arcarrow{182}{269}{ CHECK }
   \arcarrow{176}{ 96}{ ACT   }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I remove the arrow-like shape and take a simple curved-like rectangle? 
[image]

That is I want to remove the start and the end of the arcarrow object that gives rise to the puzzle effect and a preferred orientation.

[image]

Comment: What is a curved-like rectangle? Could you perhaps add a sketch?

Comment: @marmot Thanks for the comment. I apologize for not being clear. The plan, do, check, act text are inside arrow-like shapes thanks to the command `\arcarrow`. I just want to modify slightly the stard and the end of these shapes in order that there is not preferred sense or stating differently removing the puzzle-like effect.

Comment: For that you only need to modify the `\fill` command to become `\fill[mygray, very thick] (\astart+\atip:\rin)
                         arc (\astart+\atip:\aend:\rin)
      -- (\aend:\rout)   arc (\aend:\astart+\atip:\rout)
   -- cycle;`, i.e. drop two coordinates from that path.

Comment: @marmot It's almost there! Thank you very much. Is it possible to decrease the distance between the previous end and the following start?

Comment: @marmot I found it on my own! Just one thing how is possible to change the circle radious to 2 (I know that) but keep the distance of the curved shapes to the circle as it was?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it might be cleaner to write an answer than scattering the information over too many comments.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{208,208,208}
\definecolor{mymagenta}{RGB}{226,0,116}
\newcommand*{\mytextstyle}{\sffamily\Large\bfseries\color{black!85}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \fill[mymagenta] circle (1.35);
   \node at (0,0) [
      font  = \mytextstyle,
      color = white,
      align = center
   ]{
      PDCA\\
      Cycle
   };
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\mydist}{2}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\Radius}{2}
    \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {PLAN,DO,CHECK,ACT}
    {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{sign(sin(180-\mydist-90*\Y))}
    \ifnum\itest>0
    \draw[mygray,line width=1cm,postaction={decoration = {
         text along path,
         text = {|\mytextstyle|\X},
         text align = {align = center},
         raise = -1.0ex
      },
      decorate}] (180-\mydist-90*\Y:\Radius) arc(180-\mydist-90*\Y:90+\mydist-90*\Y:\Radius);
    \else
    \draw[mygray,line width=1cm,postaction={decoration = {
         text along path,
         text = {|\mytextstyle|\X},
         text align = {align = center},
         raise = -1.0ex
      },
      decorate}] (90+\mydist-90*\Y:\Radius) arc(90+\mydist-90*\Y:180-\mydist-90*\Y:\Radius);
    \fi  
      } 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's amazing! But the orientation of Do and Check text is reversed (pi rad).

Comment: @Dimitris Good catch! Fixed it.

Comment: I don't know if I should open a new thread but when I type something like `\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {Déplacement,Vélocité, Rapidité, Dépa}` the words appears without the accents even though the preambule contains french babel loading. I tried also `D\'{e}pa` but still the behavior rests the same.

Comment: @Dimitris When using `decorations.text`, one has to "protect" these characters. E.g. `\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {PLAN,DO,CHECK,D{\'{e}}pa} ...` works because there are `{` and `}` around this symbol, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/481935/121799 for a related problem.

Comment: `TeX` SE is better than a book about `LaTeX`. Thank you very much once again! I did as you said and everything is ok!

Answer (score 2):

The [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote, can be used.

The initial settings are `value=\WCvarA`, `slices style=\WCvarB` and `data=\WCvarC`. For this figure, we set `value=1` so that each slice is the same size. We also set the key `data` empty.

The text in the arcs is given to the key `arc data`. The direction of this text depends on the angle of the middle of the arc given by `\WCmidangle` which is used in the key `arc data dir`. The position of this text is determined by the key `arc data pos`.

The gaps between the slices are obtained with the key `gap`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{208,208,208}
\definecolor{mymagenta}{RGB}{226,0,116}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\sffamily\Large\bfseries\color{black!85}
\fill[mymagenta] (0,0) circle[radius=1.5];
\wheelchart[
  arc data=\WCvarA,
  arc data dir={\WCmidangle<180?1:-1},
  arc data pos=0.5,
  data=,
  gap,
  middle=PDCA\\Cycle,
  radius={1.7}{2.7},
  slices style=mygray,
  value=1
]{PLAN,DO,CHECK,ACT}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Wow, more than four year ago. I have totally forgotten my question. I really appreciate your answer!