# Modifying the colors of arcarrow

Tags: tikz-pgf

This code is from @marmot's reply here : [Modifying arcarrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485680/modifying-arcarrow)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{208,208,208}
\definecolor{mymagenta}{RGB}{226,0,116}
\newcommand*{\mytextstyle}{\sffamily\Large\bfseries\color{black!85}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \fill[mymagenta] circle (1.35);
   \node at (0,0) [
      font  = \mytextstyle,
      color = white,
      align = center
   ]{
      PDCA\\
      Cycle
   };
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\mydist}{2}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\Radius}{2}
    \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {PLAN,DO,CHECK,ACT}
    {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{sign(sin(180-\mydist-90*\Y))}
    \ifnum\itest>0
    \draw[mygray,line width=1cm,postaction={decoration = {
         text along path,
         text = {|\mytextstyle|\X},
         text align = {align = center},
         raise = -1.0ex
      },
      decorate}] (180-\mydist-90*\Y:\Radius) arc(180-\mydist-90*\Y:90+\mydist-90*\Y:\Radius);
    \else
    \draw[mygray,line width=1cm,postaction={decoration = {
         text along path,
         text = {|\mytextstyle|\X},
         text align = {align = center},
         raise = -1.0ex
      },
      decorate}] (90+\mydist-90*\Y:\Radius) arc(90+\mydist-90*\Y:180-\mydist-90*\Y:\Radius);
    \fi  
      } 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is is possible to have each arcarrow object with a different color? Thank you very much.

Comment: You could use this approach: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/433631

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colours come from the draw command and, in particular, from the use of the colour `mygray`. All that you need to do is change them. For example, you can use a different colour for each by adding a colour to the `\foreach` loop:

[image]

Here is an update of marmot's nice code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{208,208,208}
\definecolor{mymagenta}{RGB}{226,0,116}
\newcommand*{\mytextstyle}{\sffamily\Large\bfseries\color{black!85}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \fill[mymagenta] circle (1.35);
   \node at (0,0) [
      font  = \mytextstyle,
      color = white,
      align = center
   ]{
      PDCA\\
      Cycle
   };
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\mydist}{2}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\Radius}{2}
    \foreach \X/\col [count=\Y] in {PLAN/blue!10,DO/red!10,CHECK/green!10,ACT/orange!10}
    {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{sign(sin(180-\mydist-90*\Y))}
    \ifnum\itest>0
    \draw[\col,line width=1cm,postaction={decoration = {
         text along path,
         text = {|\mytextstyle|\X},
         text align = {align = center},
         raise = -1.0ex
      },
      decorate}] (180-\mydist-90*\Y:\Radius) arc(180-\mydist-90*\Y:90+\mydist-90*\Y:\Radius);
    \else
    \draw[\col,line width=1cm,postaction={decoration = {
         text along path,
         text = {|\mytextstyle|\X},
         text align = {align = center},
         raise = -1.0ex
      },
      decorate}] (90+\mydist-90*\Y:\Radius) arc(90+\mydist-90*\Y:180-\mydist-90*\Y:\Radius);
    \fi
      }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! And I if want to change the color of the text in the arcarrow object, say, from black to white?

Comment: I found it! It was not difficult at all! Thanks again.

Comment: @Dimitris Great. The [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) manual is pretty readable...the only problem is that it's so bloody long:)